# Hard time creating a class scope for HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, scopes

This is my simplified situation:

```
class Producer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rules
end

class Rule
  has_and_belongs_to_many :producers
end
```

But `Rule` happens to follow a STI structure. So I have this:

```
class Producer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rules

  has_and_belongs_to_many :product_rules, join_table: :producers_rules,
    association_foreign_key: :rule_id

  has_and_belongs_to_many :fee_rules, join_table: :producers_rules
    association_foreign_key: :rule_id
end

class Rule
  has_and_belongs_to_many :producers
end

class ProductRule < Rule
end

class FeeRule < Rule
end
```

No big deal, works out just fine. So now I want to create a scope that returns only `Producers` that are related to `ProductRules`

Something equivalent to this:

```
Producer.all.select{|x| x.product_rules.any? }
```

Can anyone point out a quick solution?

NOTE: I obvioulsy don't want to load all producers and select them afterward, I want to directly load only the right ones

---

UPDATE

Im using Rails version 2.3.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every association between `Producer` and one of `Rule`'s subclasses is going to create a separate record on the join table. You can use that fact and select all the `Producer`s that have any record on the join table pointing to them (taking care to select the correct `type`):

In Rails 2.x:

```
class Producer
  def self.with_some_product_rule
    scoped(conditions: <<-SQL)
      producers.id IN (
        SELECT producer_id FROM producers_rules
        INNER JOIN rules ON rules.id = producers_rules.rule_id
        WHERE rules.type = 'ProductRule'
      )
    SQL
  end
end
```